# No Iphone devices available in Simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, expo

my expo version: "^35.0.0"
react version: "16.8.3"
expo cli version: "3.1.0"
xcode version: "11.0"
This is the error that I ran into when I try to run ios simulator: 
"There was a problem booting a device in iOS Simulator. Quit Simulator, and try again.
Error installing or running app. Error: No iPhone devices available in Simulator."

Comment: I am having the same issue see error => 
"There was a problem booting a device in iOS Simulator. Quit Simulator, and try again.
Error installing or running app. Error: No iPhone devices available in Simulator."

Comment: @OdeyinkaOlubunmi yes and I can only run it on my real device under the expo app. Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 1):

I first try creating a normal non-Expo app via XCode (i.e. got through the "new app" flow there - any kind of app, doesn't matter, you don't need to write any code).
Then try launching this newly created, pure-XCode app. And that works for me meaning xcode works fine.

I decided to remove and reinstall Expo. While re-installing I noticed that some of the folders used for installation are owned by root and I have some errors while installing. I change the ownership of those folders to my username on my mac. i.e. "sudo chown -R ownerName: /usr/local/lib/node_modules"

I tried to run a new expo project again and got write access issues to a facebook watchman directory, i did the same thing i did above by granting write control of this directory to my logged on account instead of the default root which is the owner of the folder at the time of error.

I tried to run my app using IOS simulator again and everything now work fine

Comment: https://forums.expo.io/t/help-xcode-11-simulator-doesnt-show-expo-app/28070/9 I got some help from people in the expo community and resolved the problem. It's working fine now. Thank you for your help too.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed XCode successfully and the simulator is running without any issues then do the following:

navigate to the expo project.

run `sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.expo/`

run `sudo rm -rf ~/.expo` and then `npm start`

this will download the Expo GO app on your simulator.